# map over columns and extract the first number using map_dbl

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following data:

```
                      08001          08003            08005        08006    08007          08009           08010_AM         08014_AM      0801501
08001    4875.276, 4875.276   8.448, 8.448   16.876, 16.876 14.56, 14.56     NULL 15.066, 15.066     24.953, 24.953     7.229, 7.229 7.074, 7.074
08003                15.632         3663.7           15.794      129.029   13.371        145.019               NULL           12.382      180.696
08005                10.611          4.911         2474.452       29.844     NULL          43.95               NULL          347.076         NULL
08006                 7.291         69.755           29.844     10841.55 4947.665        200.296               NULL           25.047       19.926
08007                  NULL          33.67           17.269     4954.248 3875.372        111.159               NULL             NULL         9.84
08009                32.811        106.313           58.019      145.959  158.566       2791.247               NULL            6.568        12.59
08010_AM     40.875, 40.875           NULL     4.341, 4.341         NULL     NULL           NULL 3039.333, 3039.333     4.341, 4.341         NULL
08014_AM       4.732, 4.732 10.249, 10.249 311.877, 311.877 6.568, 6.568     NULL 10.831, 10.831       4.341, 4.341 420.177, 420.177 6.172, 6.172
0801501              12.344        220.281             NULL       32.741     NULL         18.797               NULL            6.172     1069.609
0801502               23.21        293.464           13.865        34.51    5.624         29.219               NULL             NULL     4779.908
```

Where some of the columns have two numeric values in them. I can use the following to map over the columns and take an average:

```
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ map_dbl(.x, mean, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

However, this takes too long on the whole dataset. I notice that all of the duplicate column numerics are the same, so my question is how can I change the `map` function to instead of computing the mean over the two numerics, take the first numeric value?

i.e. in column 1 `08001` there are the values `40.875, 40.875`, so instead of taking the average of these two numbers, how can I just extract the first number?
Data:

```
df <- structure(list(`08001` = list(c(4875.276, 4875.276), 15.632, 
    10.611, 7.291, NULL, 32.811, c(40.875, 40.875), c(4.732, 
    4.732), 12.344, 23.21), `08003` = list(c(8.448, 8.448), 3663.7, 
    4.911, 69.755, 33.67, 106.313, NULL, c(10.249, 10.249), 220.281, 
    293.464), `08005` = list(c(16.876, 16.876), 15.794, 2474.452, 
    29.844, 17.269, 58.019, c(4.341, 4.341), c(311.877, 311.877
    ), NULL, 13.865), `08006` = list(c(14.56, 14.56), 129.029, 
    29.844, 10841.553, 4954.248, 145.959, NULL, c(6.568, 6.568
    ), 32.741, 34.51), `08007` = list(NULL, 13.371, NULL, 4947.665, 
    3875.372, 158.566, NULL, NULL, NULL, 5.624), `08009` = list(
    c(15.066, 15.066), 145.019, 43.95, 200.296, 111.159, 2791.247, 
    NULL, c(10.831, 10.831), 18.797, 29.219), `08010_AM` = list(
    c(24.953, 24.953), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(3039.333, 
    3039.333), c(4.341, 4.341), NULL, NULL), `08014_AM` = list(
    c(7.229, 7.229), 12.382, 347.076, 25.047, NULL, 6.568, c(4.341, 
    4.341), c(420.177, 420.177), 6.172, NULL), `0801501` = list(
    c(7.074, 7.074), 180.696, NULL, 19.926, 9.84, 12.59, NULL, 
    c(6.172, 6.172), 1069.609, 4779.908), `0801502` = list(c(26.747, 
26.747), 305.18, 17.419, 27.801, 5.624, 20.512, NULL, NULL, 4948.395, 
    3647.42)), row.names = c("08001", "08003", "08005", "08006", 
"08007", "08009", "08010_AM", "08014_AM", "0801501", "0801502"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `imap_dfc` -

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

imap_dfc(df, function(x, y) 
  tibble(!!y := map_dbl(x, ~if(length(.x)) .x[1] else NA)))

#    `08001` `08003` `08005` `08006` `08007` `08009` `08010_AM` `08014_AM`
#     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 4875.      8.45   16.9   1.46e1   NA       15.1      25.0        7.23
# 2   15.6  3664.     15.8   1.29e2   13.4    145.       NA         12.4 
# 3   10.6     4.91 2474.    2.98e1   NA       44.0      NA        347.  
# 4    7.29   69.8    29.8   1.08e4 4948.     200.       NA         25.0 
# 5   NA      33.7    17.3   4.95e3 3875.     111.       NA         NA   
# 6   32.8   106.     58.0   1.46e2  159.    2791.       NA          6.57
# 7   40.9    NA       4.34 NA        NA       NA      3039.         4.34
# 8    4.73   10.2   312.    6.57e0   NA       10.8       4.34     420.  
# 9   12.3   220.     NA     3.27e1   NA       18.8      NA          6.17
#10   23.2   293.     13.9   3.45e1    5.62    29.2      NA         NA   
# … with 2 more variables: 0801501 <dbl>, 0801502 <dbl>
```

The output of above is a tibble and tibbles do not support rownames. If you want to preserve the rownames take this base R approach -

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) 
  sapply(x, function(y) if(length(y)) y[1] else NA))
df

#            08001    08003    08005     08006    08007    08009
#08001    4875.276    8.448   16.876    14.560       NA   15.066
#08003      15.632 3663.700   15.794   129.029   13.371  145.019
#08005      10.611    4.911 2474.452    29.844       NA   43.950
#08006       7.291   69.755   29.844 10841.553 4947.665  200.296
#08007          NA   33.670   17.269  4954.248 3875.372  111.159
#08009      32.811  106.313   58.019   145.959  158.566 2791.247
#08010_AM   40.875       NA    4.341        NA       NA       NA
#08014_AM    4.732   10.249  311.877     6.568       NA   10.831
#0801501    12.344  220.281       NA    32.741       NA   18.797
#0801502    23.210  293.464   13.865    34.510    5.624   29.219

#         08010_AM 08014_AM  0801501  0801502
#08001      24.953    7.229    7.074   26.747
#08003          NA   12.382  180.696  305.180
#08005          NA  347.076       NA   17.419
#08006          NA   25.047   19.926   27.801
#08007          NA       NA    9.840    5.624
#08009          NA    6.568   12.590   20.512
#08010_AM 3039.333    4.341       NA       NA
#08014_AM    4.341  420.177    6.172       NA
#0801501        NA    6.172 1069.609 4948.395
#0801502        NA       NA 4779.908 3647.420
```

Comment: Thanks! is there anyway to preserve the rownames?

Comment: I just added a base R approach which will preserve the rownames.

Comment: Thanks! the base R code works, I have a list of similar dataframes I want to apply the `lapply` over, do you have any idea how I can apply the base R code to each element of the list? I can provide some more data if needed. My original idea was to do something like: `list %>% map(., ~  imap_dfc(., function(x, y) 
    tibble(!!y := map_dbl(x, ~if(length(.x)) .x[1] else NA))) )`

Comment: You may need another `lapply` over it : `df[] <- lapply(list, function(df) lapply(df, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) if(length(y)) y[1] else NA)))`

Comment: I think the following works for me`mutate(across(where(is.list), ~ map(., first)))` which just extracts the first list item.

Comment: Yes, that works but your column is still a list.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated** I have made some modifications to my first solution to get the desired output, there had been a problem with the output which I didn't notice.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  map_dfc(~ .x %>% map_dbl(~ if(is.null(.x)) NA else .x[1]))

# A tibble: 10 x 10
   `08001` `08003` `08005`  `08006` `08007` `08009` `08010_AM` `08014_AM` `0801501` `0801502`
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 4875.      8.45   16.9     14.6    NA       15.1      25.0        7.23      7.07     26.7 
 2   15.6  3664.     15.8    129.     13.4    145.       NA         12.4     181.      305.  
 3   10.6     4.91 2474.      29.8    NA       44.0      NA        347.       NA        17.4 
 4    7.29   69.8    29.8  10842.   4948.     200.       NA         25.0      19.9      27.8 
 5   NA      33.7    17.3   4954.   3875.     111.       NA         NA         9.84      5.62
 6   32.8   106.     58.0    146.    159.    2791.       NA          6.57     12.6      20.5 
 7   40.9    NA       4.34    NA      NA       NA      3039.         4.34     NA        NA   
 8    4.73   10.2   312.       6.57   NA       10.8       4.34     420.        6.17     NA   
 9   12.3   220.     NA       32.7    NA       18.8      NA          6.17   1070.     4948.  
10   23.2   293.     13.9     34.5     5.62    29.2      NA         NA      4780.     3647.
```

Or else we can use `map_depth`:

```
df %>%
  map_depth(2, ~ if(is.null(.x)) NA_real_ else .x[1]) %>%
  map_dfc(~ .x %>% unlist)

# A tibble: 10 x 10
   `08001` `08003` `08005`  `08006` `08007` `08009` `08010_AM` `08014_AM` `0801501` `0801502`
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 4875.      8.45   16.9     14.6    NA       15.1      25.0        7.23      7.07     26.7 
 2   15.6  3664.     15.8    129.     13.4    145.       NA         12.4     181.      305.  
 3   10.6     4.91 2474.      29.8    NA       44.0      NA        347.       NA        17.4 
 4    7.29   69.8    29.8  10842.   4948.     200.       NA         25.0      19.9      27.8 
 5   NA      33.7    17.3   4954.   3875.     111.       NA         NA         9.84      5.62
 6   32.8   106.     58.0    146.    159.    2791.       NA          6.57     12.6      20.5 
 7   40.9    NA       4.34    NA      NA       NA      3039.         4.34     NA        NA   
 8    4.73   10.2   312.       6.57   NA       10.8       4.34     420.        6.17     NA   
 9   12.3   220.     NA       32.7    NA       18.8      NA          6.17   1070.     4948.  
10   23.2   293.     13.9     34.5     5.62    29.2      NA         NA      4780.     3647.
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `map` with `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(),
      ~ map_dbl(., function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA_real_ else x[1])))
      08001   08003    08005    08006    08007    08009 08010_AM 08014_AM  0801501  0801502
1  4875.276   8.448   16.876    14.56       NA   15.066   24.953    7.229    7.074   26.747
2    15.632  3663.7   15.794  129.029   13.371  145.019       NA   12.382  180.696   305.18
3    10.611   4.911 2474.452   29.844       NA    43.95       NA  347.076       NA   17.419
4     7.291  69.755   29.844 10841.55 4947.665  200.296       NA   25.047   19.926   27.801
5        NA   33.67   17.269 4954.248 3875.372  111.159       NA       NA     9.84    5.624
6    32.811 106.313   58.019  145.959  158.566 2791.247       NA    6.568    12.59   20.512
7    40.875      NA    4.341       NA       NA       NA 3039.333    4.341       NA       NA
8     4.732  10.249  311.877    6.568       NA   10.831    4.341  420.177    6.172       NA
9    12.344 220.281       NA   32.741       NA   18.797       NA    6.172 1069.609 4948.395
10    23.21 293.464   13.865    34.51    5.624   29.219       NA       NA 4779.908  3647.42
```